# How to bring Radio Buttons inside an html link using Javascript

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I’m looking for some help bringing Radio buttons that we have on a page inside a link. At the moment we have a Quiz with various questions with 4 possible choices for the respondent to choose. The text links work fine and advance the user to the next page, but the radio buttons don’t work. They are clickable, but they don’t advance you to the next page.

How would I bring the Radio buttons inside the link? I want the Radio buttons to send you forward, just like the text links.

Here is the test page for the Quiz (need to press Start Quiz to see the Radio buttons):

http://stephanieshipper.com/test/

Here is the piece of code from the .js file:

```js
function updates(questions) {

 for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

  $("body").append("<article><p>" + questions[i] + "</p><input id='question-" + (i*10) + "-1' type='radio' order='1' name='question-" + i + "-0'><label for='question-" + (i*10) + "-1'>exactly like me</label><br><input id='question-" + (i*100) + "-2' type='radio' order='2' name='question-" + i + "-0'><label for='question-" + (i*100) + "-2'>sort of like me</label><br><input id='question-" + (i*1000) + "-3' type='radio' order='3' name='question-" + i + "-0'><label for='question-" + (i*1000) + "-3'>not really like me</label><br><input id='question-" + (i*10000) + "-4' type='radio' order='4' name='question-" + i + "-0'><label for='question-" + (i*1000) + "-4'>not at all like me</label><br></article>");

}

 motions();

}



function motions() {

 var step = 1;

 results = [];

 var order;

 $("body > article > label").on("click", function() {

  $(this).parent().hide(250);

  if (step < 20) {

   $(this).parent().next().show(250);

   order = parseInt($(this).prev().attr("order"));

   results[step-1] = order;

   step++;

  } else {
```

Comment: If you're going to have the radio buttons forward immediately after selection, you might consider just getting rid of them entirely. Most surveys employ radio buttons so you can consider your selection (or change it) before you move on to the next step.

Comment: Don't put radio buttons inside a link.

Comment: what about binding a change event (on select or on change) over the radio buttons and on change make a redirect with window.location?

Comment: Okay, so, if I was going remove the Radio buttons, how would I best edit the code above? I've tried a quick attempt, but it left me with long input boxes in the place of the Radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

As I see, your are calling the next page just if the user click on the label tag :

```
$("body > article > label").on("click", function() {}
```

What you gonna need to do it's adding the radio button(your input tag), into this jquery

eg.:

```
$("input[type='radio']")
```

So maybe would work :

```
$("body > article >input[type='radio'] > label").on("click", function() {}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Sadly, it doesn't work. When I try this, the Radio buttons don't advance the Quiz, and worse still, the links themselves now don't work. So, I reversed out the change. Is it a syntax issue? Any other ideas about how to incorporate this addition?